# How to set mpm prefork for c3.xlarge in ec2 instance

Tags: apache

Can any one help me out set apache mpm prefork for 7.5GB RAM and 4Core CPU.

How to calculate mpm parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to support 8000 concurrent connections in that case you can use below configuration. Where ServerLimit * ThreadsPerChild which in below example is 250 * 32 = 8000

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
ServerLimit             250
StartServers             10
MinSpareThreads          75
MaxSpareThreads         250 
ThreadLimit              64
ThreadsPerChild          32
MaxClients             8000
MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If i am setting the above configuration what is the maximum CPU load it will support? It is a 4 Virtual EC2 core and what is the maximum load average for this server to be work fine. I understood about maximum clients parameter. Please explain me about other parameter also. Thank you.

Comment: CPU Load will depend on code as well on how Apache would be using system resources out of it. You can look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html